# IUPAC nomenclature of chelates

Tags: nomenclature, coordination-compounds

I could finally get a copy of the Red Book 2005 from a library. In the chapter dedicated to nomenclature of coordinate complexes, while explaining the κ-system of specifying donor atoms, the following two examples were given (among many others):

[image]

Can anyone explain how the naming is done for the two compounds (labelled 2 and 3 in the picture)? The problem that I am facing is with the closed rings. From where is the naming started?

Answer (score 1):

The image gives a thousand words, it is difficult to say how many words the colorized image gives, but might help.

[image: partially selectively multi-colorized original image]